# How to stay login while using a regex?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to run a `regex` command to reach some content which is accessible only if I log in.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, re

username = 'USERNAME'

password = 'PWD'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})

opener.open('https://example.com/account/login.html/?next=/', login_data)

AQK=opener.open('http://example.com/membercontent')

AQJ=AQK.read()

regex='<p class="grid_3 prefix_1 data ">(.+?)</p>'

pattern=re.compile(regex)

content=re.findall(pattern,AQJ)

print content
```

When I run the command above `python` doesn't reach the content I'm looking for. It answers `[]`.

I'm sure that the regex command is correct because it works if I try to reach non-member content.

Comment: Have you tried the simple step of printing out `AQJ`? That should give you all the information you need to verify what you're searching for is there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `AQJ` does not contain the regex you are looking for. Look carefully that the login process is performed correctly.

The variable `AQJ` holds a string after the command `AQK.read()` is performed, so the return value of `content` does not depend on the connection status at the moment the regex command is performed.